Generate Hopf bifurcation diagram for 3D system in Matlab
Hello I want to plot the Hopf bifurcation diagram for the 3D system.
I have this code but I'm getting nothing other than straight lines.
How would I fix this? Any help is appreciated. The parameter set is fine because I generated other time series graphs for the model with it fine.
% Parameters
r=3;
a=0.2;
b=2;
gamma=0.3;
m=0.92;
c=2.5;
alpha=10;
p=100.001;
q=0.01;

% Define the range of parameter values for bifurcation diagram
eta_values = linspace(0, 3, 1000);  % Range of 'eta' values

% Arrays to store results
x_result = zeros(size(eta_values));
y_result = zeros(size(eta_values));
z_result = zeros(size(eta_values));

% Initial conditions (for detecting the Hopf bifurcation)
x0 = 1000;
y0 = 200;
z0 = 600;

% Iterate over each 'eta' value
for i = 1:length(eta_values)
    eta = eta_values(i);
    
    % Solve the system using ODE45
    tspan = [0 1000];  % Time span for integration
    odefun = @(t, Y) [r*Y(1)*(1-Y(1)/Y(3))-a*(1-m)*Y(1)*Y(2)/(1+gamma*(1-m)*Y(1));
                      b*(1-m)*Y(1)*Y(2)/(1+gamma*(1-m)*Y(1))-c*Y(2);
                      (Y(3)-alpha)*(p-Y(3))/(q+Y(3));];
    [~, Y] = ode45(odefun, tspan, [x0; y0; z0]);
    
    % Check for Hopf bifurcation (change in stability)
    % Look for oscillatory behavior in the solution
    if i > 1
        if abs(Y(end, 1) - x_result(i-1)) > 0.01
            fprintf('Hopf bifurcation detected at eta = %f\n', eta);
        end
    end
    
    % Record the final values (or a characteristic of the solution)
    x_result(i) = Y(end, 1);
    y_result(i) = Y(end, 2);
    z_result(i) = Y(end, 3);
end

% Plot the bifurcation diagram
figure;
plot(eta_values, x_result, '.k', 'MarkerSize', 1);
hold on;
plot(eta_values, y_result, '.b', 'MarkerSize', 1);
plot(eta_values, z_result, '.r', 'MarkerSize', 1);
xlabel('\eta');
ylabel('Steady State Values');
legend('x', 'y', 'z');
title('Hopf Bifurcation Diagram');
grid on;


How sure are you that there is a bifurcation in your parameter subset?

@LutzLehmann I have an analytical proof that Hopf and transcritical bifurcation exists

Then you should be able to verify the quantitative preconditions of that proof for the numerical setup. Any ad-hoc, non-optimized implementation should do.
